# CSS - position absolute not perfectly centering with CSS variables

Tags: html, css

I am using a pure CSS loading spinner (kudos to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp) for the idea) which is being positioned with `position: absolute;` To then center it, I use `calc(50% - (spinner's width-or-height / 2));`

To see it in action I made a jsfiddle which demonstrates it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4lackof/7vkygtds/2/) (snippet below). The idea is that `.pure-center` is a flex-box which centers a smaller circle with `align-items: center; justify-content: center;` thus giving a pure center element. However, when compared to my spinner I position with `position: absolute;` you can see that the y-axis works out correctly (it's in the middle vertically), but the x-axis is a little to the right.

Here's a snippet demonstrating it:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.pure-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.pure-center > div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
.spinner {
  --size: 48px; /* Creates variable for height and width */
  animation: norm-spin .65s linear infinite;
  border: 8px solid white;
  border-top: 8px solid #369;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: var(--size);
  left: calc(50% - (var(--size) / 2));
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - (var(--size) / 2));
  transition: 0.25s;
  width: var(--size);
  z-index: 1;
}

/*\
 * I feel this is REALLY hacky,
 * but it is a way of adding another border around the spinner
\*/
.spinner:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: -9px;
  left: -9px;
  right: -9px;
  bottom: -9px;
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
@keyframes norm-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pure-center">
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="spinner"></div>
```

**Does anyone know why my method of positioning a `position: absolute;` would work vertically but not horizontally, when it is the same code (I use CSS variables `--size: 48px;`) which does the vertical *and* horizontal positioning?**

Comment: `left: calc(48.9% - (var(--size) / 2));` check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is just how I would handle it... set the main parent item to control position, height, and width. Then the children divs that create the spinner would all adjust accordingly. You can then change the width/height of `.spinhold` and it will enlarge/reduce without altering the animation or inner circle. (actual spinner will stay at 9px though unless adjusted)

In addition, you don't need to be concerned about changing the inner circle fill color to match any background.. the center is transparent.

I'm not a fan of using CSS variables yet, they aren't supported well enough and flex is great, but I wouldn't feel the need for it here.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.2) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.2)100%);
}

/* center holder*/
.spinhold { 
  position: relative; 
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height:50px; 
  width: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #aaa; /* outer border  */
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0, .3);}


.spinborder {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px; /* compensates for border on spinhold */
  left: -1px; /* compensates for border on spinhold */
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px; /* width of spin border + 1px for border on this element */
  width: calc(100% - 20px); /* spinhold width - (left + right) margin */
  height: calc(100% - 20px); /* spinhold height - (left + right) margin */
  border: 1px solid #aaa; /* inner border */
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
  }

.spin {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0; 
  width: calc(100% - 18px); /* spinhold width - this border width * 2 */
  height: calc(100% - 18px) ; /* spinhold height - this border width * 2 */
  border: 9px solid #eee; /* spin track color */
  border-bottom-color: #00e; /* color of spinner */
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  animation: norm-spin .65s linear infinite;
  
  }
    
@keyframes norm-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinhold">
  <div class="spinborder"></div>
  <div class="spin"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the border width in your calculation.

Why it isn't exaclty 64px, i can't tell. Somehow 62px is perfekt..

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pure-center {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  left: calc(50% - 20px);
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.pure-center > div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.spinner {
  --size: 48px; /* Creates variable for height and width */
  --sizeWidthBorder: 62px;
  animation: norm-spin .65s linear infinite;
  border: 8px solid white;
  border-top: 8px solid #369;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: var(--size);
  left: calc(50% - (var(--sizeWidthBorder) / 2));
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - (var(--sizeWidthBorder) / 2));
  transition: 0.25s;
  width: var(--size);
  z-index: 1;
}


/*\
 * This is REALLY hacky, but it adds another border around the spinner
\*/

.spinner:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: -9px;
  left: -9px;
  right: -9px;
  bottom: -9px;
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

@keyframes norm-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pure-center">
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="spinner"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

update one property in `.spinner`

```
left: calc(50% - (var(--size) / 2) - 8px);
```

Since you have given a `border` of `8px`, you need to subtract that from the `left` property

Here is the updated **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7vkygtds/3/)**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pure-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.pure-center > div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.spinner {
  --size: 48px; /* Creates variable for height and width */
  animation: norm-spin .65s linear infinite;
  border: 8px solid white;
  border-top: 8px solid #369;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: var(--size);
  left: calc(50% - (var(--size) / 2) - 8px);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - (var(--size) / 2));
  transition: 0.25s;
  width: var(--size);
  z-index: 1;
}


/*\
 * This is REALLY hacky, but it adds another border around the spinner
\*/

.spinner:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: -9px;
  left: -9px;
  right: -9px;
  bottom: -9px;
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

@keyframes norm-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pure-center">
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="spinner"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is just because you are using border 8px.

```
left: calc(50% - 32px);
```

If you don't want to hard code it, consider border, add **16px** to it's width